# Mac OS Catalina "to open eclipse you need to install the legacy java se 6 runtime"

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, macos-catalina, legacy

**PROBLEM :** Although I successfully installed Java JDK Kit and Eclipse on my MacOS Catalina 10.15, I cannot launch Eclipse. I get this error message:

"To open eclipse you need to install the legacy java se 6 runtime"

**BACKGROUND :**
I am starting to learn java programming. I wanted to install java and eclipse. Following a helpful [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxi3iIy4F5A&t=138s), I successfully installed java. I also set up the JAVA_HOME variable. Terminal confirms that I have installed

- java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
  Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
  Java Hotspot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
- javac version javac 14.0.1

I also installed eclipse on my macbook watching a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gufMbpxzfWw&t=509s).

However, Eclipse doesn't launch showing the error message.
"to open eclipse you need to install the legacy java se 6 runtime"

WHAT I TRIED TO TROUBLE SHOOT:

Message comes as

- *"to open eclipse you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime"
  So I click "more info" and I try to install the legacy java SE 6 runtime*

When I come to the destination select I can't install, I get the following error:

"Java for macOS 2017-001 can't be installed on this disk. A newer version of this package is already installed".

What can I do? I will need Eclipse up and running for my coding course that will start 4 days later

Comment: Do you have the newest version of eclipse?

Comment: Sounds like an old Eclipse. The current Eclipse is 2020-06 and requires at least Java 8.

Comment: I double checked after your comments. I found out that I had downloaded the installer not the file containing the latest version. I downloaded the file including the latest version and it worked! Thank you for your help! You guys are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed an old version of Eclipse which is not compatible with your Java. Uninstall it and install the latest version from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: I double checked after your comments. I found out that I had downloaded the installer not the file containing the latest version. I downloaded the file including the latest version and it worked! Thank you for your help! You guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

I change my Air late 2013 with 10.13.6 to Pro Late 2019 with 10.15.7.

I had same message with my eclipse helio 3.6 after copying his folder in /Application from old to new Mac.

I fixed that only by getting the Jdk folder

From MBA /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/ to MBP /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

I can launch Eclipse helio 3.6 and choose my new workspace location.

The power of simplicity, i just fixed this night.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).